# OS X Webview user agent won't change

Tags: macos, swift, webview, safari, user-agent

I want to make a small application that shows a website (so I can just open te app and use the website). The website only allows connections from Safari/Chrome that's why the user agent

I use these lines to change te user agent of my webview

```
let userAgent = " Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.52 Safari/537.36"
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent" : userAgent])

print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("UserAgent"))

    print(wapView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("navigator.userAgent"))
```

The console then prints:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.52 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

And the website doesn't open. I don't know why it won't change. Any suggestions?
I use these lines to create the request:

```
let uUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.websiteUrl.com")
let reqq = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: uUrl!)

self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(reqq)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing user agent for custom webview using swift

```
// Remember to import proper library for webview
import WebKit

// create url string for webview
let url = NSURL(string: "https://messenger.yahoo.com") //url of your choice
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

// the user agent of your choice, in this case safari 7.0.3
let customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A"

// this will set the user agent for your webview
webView.applicationNameForUserAgent = customUserAgent
webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
```

for a list of complete user agents see this website http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php